# Can bash conditional expression -x be seen as an if condition?

Tags: linux, bash

so I'm writing a script that's supposed to check if a package has an existing path using (bash) -x  and echo a message accordingly. How can I correctly implement my condition in the function?

I'm really out of my limited options here.

```
#!/bin/bash

exists() {
    if [[ -x $(type -P "$1" 1>hra 2>/dev/null) ]]; then

            return 0
    else
            return 1
    fi 
}

read key | exists
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] ; then

        echo $(cat hra) | echo $(awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' ) "is installed"
else
        echo $(cat hra) " needs to be installed"
fi
```

I expected the line `[[ -x $(type -P "$1" 1>hra 2>/dev/null) ]]` to be true if the path exists and is executable, but the function always returns 1.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, yes you can use `[[` with the `-x` flag as a command to be executed by `if`.  The syntax to do what you appear to be attempting would look something like

```
# Putting this in a function is silly, but whatever
exists () {
    [[ -x "$1" ]]
}

read -p "Type in a command:" key
path=$(type -P "$key")
if exists "$path"; then
    echo "${path##*/} is installed"
else
    # $path will be empty, I guess you mean $key?
    echo "need to install $path"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems in your code! isn't the following enough?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r key
if type -aP "$key"; then
    echo "$key is installed"
else
    echo "$key needs to be installed"
fi
```

Comment: Yes it is! I knew the redirection of  the file descriptor to a separate file is a bad idea, also I have 2 conditions for 1 result... I just didn't know better.I guess I need to learn A LOT more.Thank you very much for the quick response.